Set different permissions for the user and for the java application
I am writing a graphical java (javaFX) application which is a kind of shell over the operating system. I am currently using Java 8 (JDK corretto 8.402), Debian 12 and Xfce. The problem is that my Java application executes many commands and scripts with sudo. These commands are written in sudoers as NOPASSWD. It turns out that the user will be able to run all these commands with sudo without password, which is not safe.
Roughly speaking, I need to make it so that when the PC is turned on, the user is automatically logged in and the application is automatically started. Everything should be secure, the user should have very limited permissions and should not be able to execute commands that a Java application can execute.
I am not very good at Linux, so I would like to hear your suggestions.

I have tried making another user. So there is root, user1 and guest. The idea was to have the session as guest and the application run as user1.
In /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf I configured autologin for guest and in the xfce4-session-settings application I configured an autorun script to run the java application as another user like this:
sudo -S -u user1 java -jar /path/to/my.jar



I want this to run without requiring a password, but then /usr/bin/java needs to be added to sudoers as NOPASSWD. And then it turns out that the guest user can run any Java application with sudo and do whatever he wants through it.

From what I understood, as you have two users, you can grant user1 with NOPASSWD for all commands like user1   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL or even restricted to desired commands and guest doesn't need to have any sudoers rights, or if you want guest to have sudo access add a line guest   ALL=(ALL)  ALL so guest will have to provide a password.

This is really a comment, but its too long to fit in the box.

These commands are written in sudoers as NOPASSWD. It turns out that the user will be able to run all these commands with sudo without password, which is not safe.
...
Roughly speaking, I need to make it so that when the PC is turned on, the user is automatically logged in

So you want the user to be able to run the commands without having to enter a password, but you also DON'T want them to run commands without entering a password.
Your description is an oxy-moron.

The idea was to have the session as guest and the application run as user1

This is potentially making things even more complicated. While if the "application" is running as a daemon its easy enough to start up, but then it cannot interact with the screen owned by user (without additional config). OTOH if "application" is invoked by the user session then you need some mechanism to change its uid.
The best way to fix the problem is to configure the system such that the user can run the invoke the intended operations without switching uid - but you didn't tell us anything about those.
Sudo (and similar tools) exist because there are a few things that the previous approach can't fix. They are not safe if you don't use them correctly. Even something as simple as:
%support ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: less /var/log/maillog

is trivial to exploit for a root shell.

And then it turns out that the guest user can run any Java application

Because you configured sudo incorrectly. You can specify the permitted argument AS WELL AS the executable in a sudo config line.
Personally, I would always wrap the sudo target in a shell script and configure the shell script as the target in the sudo config to avoid any amibiguity.
